# Ipython: How to run the console when I have multiline code in ipython?

Tags: ipython

In the past, I could just type one line codes just press enter and it worked. But when I enter a loop(like a for-loop), when I finish typing the code for the loop, how could I run it? If I press enter, it just adds one more line in the loop and did not run.

Google says:

> To run the code, press “Enter” (or “Return”) twice . (The second “Enter” informs IPython that you are typing code and instructs IPython to execute the code.)

But when I press enter twice it only gives me two new lines in loop...

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please embed any code in your question instead of a link to an image.

Comment: The last line is missing a `)`.  In multiline mode `ipython` does not execute until all the (), [] etc are properly closed.

Comment: Thanks my fault. After adding the ) and press enter twice it worked. Thank you!

Comment: This keeps adding newlines for me and it was hard to see what was wrong (was using `def`). The shortcut is ESC + ENTER was a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html), just use the sequence <kbd>ESC</kbd> -> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

> Depending on the exact command you are typing you might realize that sometimes Enter will add a new line, and sometimes it will execute the current statement. IPython tries to guess what you are doing, so most of the time you should not have to care. Though if by any chance IPython does not do the right thing you can force execution of the current code block by pressing in sequence **Esc** and **Enter**. You can also force the insertion of a new line at the position of the cursor by using Ctrl-o.

I was defining a function and it was hard to detect what the issue was. It was a missing `'`. This forced the execution to happen, and I got an explicit error to fix.

P.S. I am on IPython 8.12.2.